# Flink stream data from S3, directories partitioned by time

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to use S3 as a data source where the objects are partitioned by hour in the following format: s3://test-data//type/.

I discovered I can use FileSource with the monitorContinuously function, but I’m trying to find a way to ensure that at any given time, it’s only checking for new files in the current hour directory.

If I use s3://test-data//type as the base path to monitor for new files, it will require terminating the job every day to prevent it from monitoring old directories.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this so that I can limit the FileSource to only monitor and read from the current hour’s directory?